# Specflow tests running on local web server

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, bdd, specflow, playwright

I am trying to use Specflow with Playwright in order to do BDD on a portal app developed but I am facing a small problem.

The Specflow project is a separate project with the ASP.Net core server that has the Api of the portal app (it is in Vue). Since the tests are pointing to a specific URL (currently localhost), before running the tests, I need to run the ASP.Net core & Vue project locally. Otherwise, Specflow & Playwright will not be able to do the test (as it will not find the localhost).

Is it any way I can force the run of the Web Server project? I tried to run it from outside Visual Studio with *dotnet build* and then *dotnet run* commands but somehow they are missing parameters (that exist while running it from inside VS) and apart from that, these commands must somehow be triggered while trying to run the tests.

I have seen solutions like creating a Docker image from a Docker Compose file in order to pack a .Net project & server in it before running the Specflow tests. Then in the *BeforeTestRun* hook using the *[FluentDocker](https://github.com/mariotoffia/FluentDocker)* to spin-up the server but I am not quite sure it is the easier (or best) solution.

Does anyone know how I can trigger running the .net core project (with the Vue pages)?

Comment: If you are on Windows, install IIS (Internet Information Services), which is a web server. Once IIS is installed, you would need to create a web application in IIS to host the ASP.NET Core web app. Just before running tests, publish the web application using `dotnet publish`. A little PowerShell scripting to make these steps easier, but isn't required.

Comment: I finally found a solution to run the project from the command line using Kestrel and then run the test cases from inside VS as normally. Running dotnetcore from the command line is not permitted to run them in IISExpress & as such it required a launch profile for Kestrel.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a pretty big question, with a pretty big answer, however this is well-trodden ground. The issue isn't so much a "specflow" issue as a general automated testing issue. Development practices like [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) and [continuous delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) can help. Each one is too big for a single question, however I can answer this in more general terms.

In its simplest form, running automated tests locally involves these steps:

1. Build the application
2. Deploy the application to a real web server
3. Run tests

I'm going to assume you are developing in a Windows environment, however every operating system has some sort of command line scripting solution available. The scripting language might change, but the overall idea will not.

1. Configure a web server. In Windows, this would be Internet Information Services (IIS).
2. Add a new "application" (or "IIS app" as some people call it) to your localhost web server. Point the physical directory to the root directory for the web project. Repeat this for each web site or web app your system requires.
3. Write a PowerShell script that gives you an easy way to build and deploy the applications to your local web server.

   This script should use publish profiles set up in Visual Studio, which allows you to publish directly from Visual Studio before invoking tests manually through Test Explorer.
4. Write a PowerShell script used has a "harness" script to coordinate building, deploying locally, and then invoking `dotnet test`.

Running tests locally just requires a single line of PowerShell to invoke your test harness script:

```
.\Scripts\Run-Tests.ps1 -solutionDir . -tags BlogPosts,Create

# Skip deploying in case web apps haven't changed:

.\Scripts\Run-Tests.ps1 -solutionDir . -tags BlogPosts,Create -deploy:False
```